# How to measure performance of angular app?

Tags: angularjs, performance

I am working on big application built using angular. I have read a lot articles how to improve performance.
I have implemented below mentioned things -

- Avoid Watchers
- ng-repeat with track by
- single binding
- Used ng-if instead of ng-show
- used **$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)** to remove ng-binding and ng-scope classes in production.

But I have tried a lot plugin but not able to get satisfactory result.

Could anybody tell me how to measure performance of angular app ??

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising: https://opbeat.com/angularjs

Other ideas:

1. Check how many watchers do you have: https://github.com/bahmutov/code-snippets/blob/master/ng-count-watchers.js
2. Check for memory leaks: http://www.dwmkerr.com/fixing-memory-leaks-in-angularjs-applications

Comment: Hey, I'm the CTO and PM of Opbeat. Would be great to get your feedback on the product and our in-dephth performance breakdown. Ping me for an invite.